# write parsley validation rules inside jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, parsley.js

I have created few payment input field, which is change based on dropdownlist value and i have also use parsley validation.now i want add to more than one parsley  validation for every input field. for example: required,minlength,numeric etc.

Here, is my jquery part.

```
$('#paytype').on('change',function(){
           var type=$(this).val();
             if(type=='1')
             {
                 $('#csh').css('display',"");
                 $('.mrn').prop('required',true);
                 $('.cdate').prop('required',true);
                 $('#cheq').css('display',"none");
                 $('#dpst').css('display',"none");
                 $('.slpno').prop('required',false);
                 $('.photo').prop('required',false);
                 $('.isdate').prop('required',false);
                 $('.bname').prop('required',false);
                 $('.cheqnum').prop('required',false);
             }
```

Html Part.

```
<div id="csh" style="display:none">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="mrn">MRN</label>
            <input type="text" name="mrn" class="form-control mrn">
            <label for="pdate">Date</label>
            <input type="date" name="cpaydate" class="form-control cdate">
            </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your're close to solutions .
Here, you can try this way.

```
var type=$(this).val();
         if(type=='1')
         {

             $('.mrn').Attr('required',true);
             $('.cdate').Attr('required',true);
             $('#cheq').Attr('display',"none");
             $('#dpst').Attr('display',"none");
             $('.slpno').Attr('required',false);
             $('.photo').Attr('required',false);

         }
```